# Retrieve data out of then accessor scope in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i am accessing an API response data using then accessor and putting it in an array

```
  ngOnInit() {
      friendRequests = []
      this.friendRequestService.getFriendRequests().then(function(response) {
           
      response.forEach(element => {
       friendRequests.push(new FriendRequest(element.id,element.receiverId,element.senderId,''));
        }); 
        console.log(friendRequests.length)
        this.freined
      }, function(err) {
          console.log(err)
      });
  
  };
```

the array is being filled inside the then scope its length is not null but outside it's empty as if it hasn't been filled with data how can I keep the data I get in the then scope?

Comment: You should declare `friendRequests` as a class member, not a local variable: `this.friendRequests = []`, `this.friendRequests.push(...)`

Comment: could you please add an answer to understand your idea propoerly ,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're storing response elements in a local variable `friendRequests` which is only defined within `ngOnInit` scope. You need to define `friendRequests` as a class member in order to be able to access it after `ngOnInit` execution has finished.

```
@Component({ ...)
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    friendRequests = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.friendRequestService.getFriendRequests().then((response) => {
            response.forEach(element => {
                this.friendRequests.push(new FriendRequest(element.id, element.receiverId, element.senderId, ''));
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });

    };
}
```

Comment: Just tried your answer i got this error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'friendRequests' of undefined

Comment: Just updated the answer (use arrow function to bind to `this`).